# Rails: How to pass params of multiple checkbox to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i built this form that generate me some chebox with value like "U6", "U8" eccc

```
<%= form.label "Seleziona Categorie" %>
      <% TeamCategory::NAMES.each do |category| %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'categories_selected[]', category -%>
      <% end %>
```

Now i have to pass the value of selected check_box to a method in my model. 
Now is:

```
def create_tournament_team_categories
    TeamCategory::NAMES.each do |name|
      team_category = TeamCategory.where(name: name).first_or_create
      self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end
  end
```

I would like to replace the TeamCategory::NAMES.each do with "selected check_box each do" and TeamCategory.where(name: name) with the value selected.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a newbie with Rails. What I see is that you took the part of the form to create the team, right?

For your code straight forward it could be:

```
<%= form.label "Seleziona Categorie" %>
      <% TeamCategory::NAMES.each do |name| %> #you are looping through team category NAMES constant
        <%= check_box_tag 'category_names_selected[]', name %>
      <% end %>
```

Your form as is allows more than one category to be selected.

For the method:

```
def create_tournament_team_categories(category_names_selected)
    category_names_selected.each do |name|
      team_category = name
      self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end
  end
```

you will probably use this method in your teams_controller.rb.  In the controller, you should be able to retrieve from params a freshly created array of selected names with something along the lines with this.

```
@category_names_selected = params[:category_names_selected]
```

I do not know how complicated your app is so it might also be nested under `["team"][:category_names_selected]` or `["team"]["category_names_selected"]` in your params hash.

To see the exact structure of the params hash and adjust the equation above you can add for example `require 'pry'` at the top of your controller file and then but the `binding.pry` just after the part where your method is executed. When you restart the server and the app hits this part of the controller you should be able to see the exact structure of your params hash in the terminal.

You can then pass the array to the method that you can call in the controller. Do not forget to add :category_names_selected to the strong params in the controller. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer... i see this error in the terminal: ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):
  app/models/tournament.rb:77:in `create_tournament_team_categories'
  app/controllers/tournaments_controller.rb:30:in `create'.

But the values is passing correctly: "category_names_selected"=>["U10", "U12", "U14"]

Comment: I assume that the method that we eddited is in the `app/models/tournament.rb:77` file on the line 77. this method expects to have one argument => `category_names_selected`  array. So it is possibly not passed in the method in your controller. Is there is a way you could post your tournaments_controller.rb here? I am particularly interested in  the method that is posted around line 30.

Comment: From what I can guess it might be the `create` method and you need to adjust it to look something like `def create 
@category_names_selected = params[:category_names_selected]`
#your code here
#and in the part where the method `create_tournament_team_categories` is used you need to edit it to look like 
`create_tournament_team_categories(@category_names_selected)`

But it is only my guess and I could give you more details if you post the controller.

Comment: Yes in line 30 i have the create method

Comment: `def create
    @tournament = Tournament.new(tournament_params)
    @tournament.sport_club = current_user.sport_club
    @category_names_selected = Tournament.new(params[:tournament][:category_names_selected])

    if @tournament.save
      redirect_to tournaments_path, notice: 'Torneo creato con successo'
    end
  end`

Comment: I have posted in answer

Comment: For the future, you can edit your initial post and add any necessary details directly to your post so that it is easier to track all the details and changes. Could you try adding `@category_names_selected` to the line `after_create :create_tournament_team_categories` and make this line look like  `after_create :create_tournament_team_categories(@category_names_selected)`?

Comment: What happens is that in your create method in the controller when you are trying to create the Tournament the controller refers to your model to do the rest of the program (the `after_create` part) here it hits an error because the method is defined with the argument and in the `after_create` part this argument is not provided and this is the reason why we are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Controller on line 30

```
def create
    @tournament = Tournament.new(tournament_params)
    @tournament.sport_club = current_user.sport_club
    @category_names_selected = params[:category_names_selected]

    if @tournament.save
      redirect_to tournaments_path, notice: 'Torneo creato con successo'
    end
  end
```

Method create_tournament_team_categories in the model

```
after_create :create_tournament_team_categories

 def create_tournament_team_categories(category_names_selected)
    @category_names_selected.each do |name|
      team_category = name
      self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end
  end
```